# PHP Delete all folder content without deleting root folder

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete the content of a folder with PHP. This folder has subfolders and files. I want to delete all but the root folder.

For example:

```
FolderFather
--Folderchild1
--FolChild2
----SubFolChild2
------Anotherfile.jpg
--MyFile.jpg
```

I want remove all folder except root directory Folder.

Comment: My best guess (i havent tried it so I am not putting it down as an answer is `array_map('unlink', glob("some/dir/*"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
function empty_dir($directory, $delete = false)
{
    $contents = glob($directory . '*');
    foreach($contents as $item)
    {
        if (is_dir($item))
            empty_dir($item . '/', true);
        else
            unlink($item);
    }
    if ($delete === true)
        rmdir($directory);
}
```

should work.

E.g. `empty_dir('/some/path/');` should empty that directory without removing,
`empty_dir('/some/path/', true);` should empty and than remove the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function deleteAll($path)
{
    $dir = dir($path);

    while ($file = $dir->read())
    {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

        $file = $path . '/' . $file;

        if (is_dir($file))
        {
            deleteAll($file);
            rmdir($file);
        }
        else
        {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `deleteAll('/path/to/FolderFather');` should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scandir()` for directory contents and `unlink()` for deleting contents.

```
<?php
$dir = "/yourfolder";
$dir_contents = scandir($dir);

foreach($dir_contents as $content)
{
    unlink($dir.'/'.$content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents = glob('path/*');     // to get all the contents
foreach ($contents as $file) {  // loop the  files
    if (is_file($file)) {
        unlink($file);          //-------  delete the file
    }
}
```